# ee.Reducer includes too many pixels

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have a simple task. Extract the frequency of each pixel value in each geometry, given:

- a ee.FeatureCollection containing 1ha (100m x 100m) geometries,
- a single band ee.Image with a pixel resolution of 25m,

`ee.reduceRegions()`
seems the function of choice. Given the geometry area and the image resolution, I would expect 16 values (i.e., pixels) per geometry, but
the reducer extracts more (20 in the example), even if I use an
`unweighted` reducer.

```js
// Define the Image and display it
var forestNonForest = ee.ImageCollection('JAXA/ALOS/PALSAR/YEARLY/FNF4')
                  .filterDate('2018-01-01', '2018-12-31');

var forestNonForestVis = {
  min: 1,
  max: 4,
  palette: ['00b200','83ef62','ffff99','0000ff'],
};
Map.setCenter(136.85, 37.37, 4);
Map.addLayer(forestNonForest, forestNonForestVis, 'Forest/Non-Forest');

var mosaic = forestNonForest.mosaic()

// Define a dummy FeatureCollection containing two point geometries, and expand it to 1 ha.
var point = ee.FeatureCollection([
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(-75.9999, 40.75034), {'name': 'Point 1'}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(-76.005, 40.755), {'name': 'Point 2'}),
])

var bufferTo1Hectare = function(feature) {
  var bufferedGeometry = feature.geometry().buffer(50).bounds(); // 50 meters buffer to achieve 1 hectare
  return feature.setGeometry(bufferedGeometry);
};

var centroid = point.map(bufferTo1Hectare);

Map.addLayer(centroid, {},'centroid')
Map.centerObject(centroid.first())

// Apply reducer
var centroid_data = mosaic.reduceRegions({
  collection: centroid,
  scale: 25,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.frequencyHistogram(), // weighted,
  // reducer: ee.Reducer.frequencyHistogram().unweighted(), // unweighted
});

// Print results for inspection
print(centroid_data)
```